Postgres XMLTABLE problem with namespaces in the XML data
I have an example XML dataset that contains a namespace reference:
<Records xmlns="http://example.com/sample.xsd">
   <Record>
     <Id>1</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>2</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>3</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>4</Id>
   </Record>
 </Records>

When I run the following query, I should get 4 rows, one for each record:
with cte_data as (
    select '<Records xmlns="http://example.com/sample.xsd">
   <Record>
     <Id>1</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>2</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>3</Id>
   </Record>
   <Record>
     <Id>4</Id>
   </Record>
 </Records>'::xml as xml_data
    )
select *
from cte_data d
left join xmltable(xmlnamespaces('xmlns="http://example.com/sample.xsd"' as x),
     'Records/Record' passing d.xml_data
     columns id text path 'Id'
     ) as x on true;

Instead, I get a single result row (the XML) without any data from the XML (id is NULL).
Interestingly, if I remove the namespace from the XML, it works just fine! The problem is that I cannot change the XML data that I'm processing to remove the namespaces. I hope that I'm merely overlooking something that someone can point out to me.
EDIT: The answer provided by @Yitzhak does work, however the true situation is a bit more complex:
with cte_data as (
    select '<Records xmlns:ns="http://example.com/sample.xsd">
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>1</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>2</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>3</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>4</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
 </Records>'::xml as xml_data
    )
select x.*
from cte_data d
, xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://example.com/sample.xsd' as "ns"),
     '/ns:Records/ns:Record' 
     passing d.xml_data
     columns id text path 'ns:Id'
     ) x

This also fails to return results.

By the way, my original answer works without changes, just changing the input data.

Please try to modify namespaces declaration as follows, and use it in XPath expression as a prefix in a proper locations.
db-fiddle
SQL
with cte_data as (
    select '<Records xmlns:ns="http://example.com/sample.xsd">
    <ns:Record>
        <ns:Id>1</ns:Id>
    </ns:Record>
    <ns:Record>
        <ns:Id>2</ns:Id>
    </ns:Record>
    <ns:Record>
        <ns:Id>3</ns:Id>
    </ns:Record>
    <ns:Record>
        <ns:Id>4</ns:Id>
    </ns:Record>
</Records>'::xml as xml_data
    )
select x.*
from cte_data d
, xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://example.com/sample.xsd' as "ns"),
     '/Records/ns:Record' 
     passing d.xml_data
     columns id text path 'ns:Id'
     ) x


Thanks! It does work, but the true use case is more complicated. Please see the revised question for more details.

I adjusted the answer. Please give it a shot.

Thank you so much, @Yitzhak!! While this example wasn't my exact situation, working on this with you pointed me in the right direction!! Awesome!!

Just do something like this to fix a bad formed namespace, should be xmlns:namespace_name="namespace_uri"
select id from
xmltable(xmlnamespaces('http://example.com/sample.xsd' as _),
'//_:Id'
passing ('<Records xmlns:ns="http://example.com/sample.xsd">
<ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>1</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>2</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>3</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
   <ns:Record>
     <ns:Id>4</ns:Id>
   </ns:Record>
 </Records>')
columns id int path 'text()') xt;

Result



id




1


2


3


4



Fiddle to test

Thanks @Pepe for showing a simpler way to present the issue!

Two forward slashes '//_:Id' is a most inefficient way to traverse XML.

@YitzhakKhabinsky its an abbreviated way of expressing a path, how is inefficient, in planning/execution time?

It is blindly traversing the entire XML tree, every single XML element.

@YitzhakKhabinsky in planning/execution with large XML documents I see similar times.
